# Derivation of $E[B_t | B_T]$ for $t<T$

Tags: brownian-motion, brownian-bridge

We know that $\begin{bmatrix} B_T \\ B_t \end{bmatrix} $ is a normal Gaussian vector and $\text{Cov}(B_T, B_t) = \min\{T,t\} = t,$ i.e,

$$
\begin{bmatrix} B_T \\ B_t \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} T & t \\ t & t \end{bmatrix}). 
$$

When deriving that $E[B_t | B_T] = \frac{t}{T}B_T$, I don't understand why

$$E[B_t | B_T] = E[B_t] + \frac{\text{Cov}(B_t, B_T)}{\text{Var}(B_T)}(B_T-E[B_T])$$

Could anyone explain this step? :)

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_conditional_expectation)